# Cacti generate old graph

Tags: linux, monitoring, linux-networking, cacti

I have a cacti system (Version 0.8.8b). The cacti system has been running for a year.

I would like to generate retroactive daily graphs, because cacti can't show the old daily graphs. 
How to generate old daily graphs?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you can't because the data is gone.

Cacti uses `rrdtool` to store the data and this tool works by storing detailed records for only a short time and then aggregating this data into lower time resolution for longer time periods. As an example, it might store data in

- 5 minute intervals for a day
- 30 min intervals for a week (averaging 6 of the last five minute data points)
- Hourly intervals for a month (again averaging the 30min data points).
- Daily intervals for a year  (see above...)

This has the advantage that each metric you record needs a fixed amount of storage but at the price of data loss from older time points.